# how to create a UI-tab from a link instead addtab button using the UI code

Tags: jquery-ui

im using the Jquery UI to manage tabs in a web page, i want to create new tabs from links in the same webpage. The content of the new tabs are another web pages...

This is the code to create a new tab but it uses the form that opens with the create tab button

```
// Actual addTab function: adds new tab using the input from the form above
function addTab() {
  var label = tabTitle.val() || "Tab " + tabCounter,
    id = "tabs-" + tabCounter,
    li = $( tabTemplate.replace( /#\{href\}/g, "#" + id ).replace( /#\{label\}/g, label ) ),
    tabContentHtml = tabContent.val() || "Tab " + tabCounter + " content.";

  tabs.find( ".ui-tabs-nav" ).append( li );
  tabs.append( "<div id='" + id + "'><p>" + tabContentHtml + "</p></div>" );
  tabs.tabs( "refresh" );
  tabCounter++;
}
```

I want to use a link to create a tab instead the button.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using this example: https://jqueryui.com/tabs/#manipulation

You would basically replace the `<button>` with an `<a>` element.

```
<div id="dialog" title="Tab data">
  <form>
    <fieldset class="ui-helper-reset">
      <label for="tab_title">Title</label>
      <input type="text" name="tab_title" id="tab_title" value="Tab Title" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
      <label for="tab_content">Content</label>
      <textarea name="tab_content" id="tab_content" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">Tab content</textarea>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>

<a id="add_tab" href="#">Add Tab</a>

<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a> <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close" role="presentation">Remove Tab</span></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Should not need to make any other changes really.

Hope that helps.